# How to query multile field on same collection in firestore

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I'm new to firebase and angular, I want to search event in the database based on selected filters and I did some searched and gathered some code to make it work and it not working properly

```
collection events{
  eventName: ...,
  eventTicketPrice,
  eventCategory
}
```

I have set up some observable to listen for changes on filter buttons and here is my code

```
  items$: Observable<any[]>;
  categoryFilter$: BehaviorSubject<string | null>;
  priceFilter$: BehaviorSubject<string | null>;
  nameFilter$: BehaviorSubject<string | null>;
  dateFilter$: BehaviorSubject<string | null>;
  ageFilter$: BehaviorSubject<string | null>;

  startAt: BehaviorSubject<string | null>;
  endAt: BehaviorSubject<string | null>;
  // startobs = this.startAt.asObservable();
  // endobs = this.endAt.asObservable();

  constructor(
    public eventService: EventsService,
    private db: AngularFirestore
  ) {}

  mobileSize = [425, 375, 320];
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.mobileSize.forEach((width) => {
      if (window.screen.width === width) {
        // 768px portrait
        this.mobile = true;
      }
    });

    this.categoryFilter$ = new BehaviorSubject(null);
    this.priceFilter$ = new BehaviorSubject(null);
    this.nameFilter$ = new BehaviorSubject(null);
    this.dateFilter$ = new BehaviorSubject(null);
    this.ageFilter$ = new BehaviorSubject(null);
    this.startAt = new BehaviorSubject(null);
    this.endAt = new BehaviorSubject(null);
    
    this.items$ = combineLatest(
      this.categoryFilter$,
      this.priceFilter$,
      this.nameFilter$,
      this.ageFilter$,
      this.startAt.pipe(debounceTime(500), distinctUntilChanged()),
      this.endAt.pipe(debounceTime(500), distinctUntilChanged())
    ).pipe(
      switchMap(([category, price, name, age, start, end]) => 
        this.db.collection('events', ref => {  
        let query : firebase.firestore.Query = ref;
        if (category !== null) { query = query.where('eventCategory', '==', category) };
        if (price == 'high' && price !== null) { query = query.orderBy('eventTicketPrice', 'desc') };
        if (price == 'low' && price !== null) { query = query.orderBy('eventTicketPrice', 'asc') };
        if (name == 'asc' && name !== null) { query = query.orderBy('eventName', 'asc') };
        if (name == 'desc' && name !== null) { query = query.orderBy('eventName', 'desc') };
        if (age !== null) { query = query.where('ageCategory', '==', age) };
        if (start && end !== null) { query = query.orderBy('eventName').startAt(start).endAt(end) };
        return query;
      }).valueChanges({ idField: 'id' }))
    );
```

currently, I'm able to filter by a single filter that is a category but I'm not able to filter data after selecting multiple filers like price filter and age filter,

basically  I want to search for data by selecting the filter

Comment: "I'm not able to filter data after selecting multiple filers" You seem to have pretty extensive query building code. What is the problem you have adding additional conditions to it?

Comment: thank you, sir, for replying, I'm trying to get events from events collection, and I have placed radio buttons(filters) and a search box in HTML with the observers, and I also have created indexes in firestore, and the above code is working properly and filters are also working but when I start a search for an event in the search box then only one filter get apply that is category, and I get no results after selecting other filters like price and age

Answer (score 0):

Your current code only adds filters for `eventCategory` and `ageCategory`. If you also want to add filters for other conditions, you'll need to add more `where` clauses to your query.

For example, if you want to **filter** on `eventTicketPrice` instead of only **ordering** on it as your code does now, you'd add:

```
...
if (price == 'high') query = query.where('eventTicketPrice', '==', 'high');
...
return query;
```